# is it possible to have a "calc embedded" indicator in doom-modeline?

Tags: mode-line, calc

this is indispensable, since I use "calc embedded" in auctex and need to leave this mode after have activate it.

Comment: Does your mode line not already say `CalcEmbed` when that is active?  Or are you saying that "doom-modeline" does not provide this standard mode-line information?

Comment: Make sure your mode line includes `mode-line-buffer-identification` in whatever its equivalent of `mode-line-format` is.  It really *should* be using that already, but maybe it just displays the buffer name.  If so, I would raise a bug report with the author.

Comment: @phils : mode-line-buffer-identification => Value: "CalcEmbed: 12 Deg LaTeX Local   ", mode-line-format =>  ("%e" (:eval (doom-modeline-format--main))). No CalcEmbed on the mode line when it is active

Comment: Right, so presumably the `doom-modeline-format--main` function never makes use of `mode-line-buffer-identification`.  I recommend that you log a bug report for that package.  Once you've done that, you can post and accept an answer which links to the upstream issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I hadn't read the documentation carefully enough. Actually, there was an icon to indicate calc-embedded mode, but in the form of an inaudible Unicode character. I installed the all-the-icons font from `M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts` and since then I have an icon indicating that I am in calc-embedded mode.